# IE ToolBar using SilverLight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is there any way to create IE ToolBar using SilverLight only (i.e. without using VC++/ATL)? Like Bing bar Tool bar from microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to build components loaded into the toolbar using Silverlight.  You can't use Silverlight to build libraries that are load into other processes.